# How to find missing files(dates) among thousands of files in a folder?

Tags: linux

I have several daily files for the years 2003-2009. the total number of the files is 2546 so there are missing dates(files) .I do not want to look on file by another to find out which dats are missing?.
the files are named like this:

```
 dat_20030129_gf.img   # so the date change from file to another
```

any command in Linux to perform this please

Comment: Only on SO is 2546 equivalent to "several"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over the date range and check if the file exists for each date. Print a warning if the file is missing. Here's an example in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'

date = Date.parse('2003-01-01')
last = Date.parse('2010-01-01')
while date < last
  filename = date.strftime("dat_%Y%m%d_gf.img")
  puts "Missing #{filename}" unless File.exist?(filename)
  date += 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that hyat was looking for a plain `bash` solution to his question. This should work, but it shows how awkward it is to process dates using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e    # exit the script if something goes wrong
enddate=$(date -u -d "2010-01-01")
date=$(date -u -d "2003-01-01")

while [[ $date != $enddate ]]; do
    filename=$(date -u -d "$date" +"dat_%Y%m%d_gf.img")
    printf "$date "  # watch the progress on the terminal
    if [[ ! -e $filename ]]; then
        echo "$filename not found"
    else
       echo  # print a newline, since printf didn't do it
    fi
    date=$(date -u -d "$date + 1 day")
done
```

The `date` command can generate any date you want with the `-d` option, and it accepts free-form input, which is why `$date + 1 day` works. I always pass `-u` to `date` to avoid problems with daylight saving time. Adding one day in the last `date` command actually adds 24 hours on my computer, but when switching to or from DST, you would need to add 23 or 25 hours to get back to the same clock time. Using `-u` for UTC avoids this problem by using a timezone that does not have DST.

Comment: Will this check work for wildcards as well. I have files that contain a time stamp at the end of when they were created which are not important.